# What IIS authentication needs enabling for custom authentication?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-identity, .net-4.6

I have developed a .NET MVC website with **.net identity** for authentication. When I deploy this onto ***IIS***, then should I enable only **anonymous authentication** so that the website handles the authentication without any IIS support?

Or should I enable anonymous auth only for 1 login page?

Should I enable **forms authentication**?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Basic" authentication should be enough.

Comment: Apparently .net identity does the auth as part of .net lifecycle and is a newer concept than the traditional forms authentication. It looks like - at the IIS level, all that is needed to make the auth with .net identity work is enabling of Anonymous authentication.